# How to scrape billboard using find_all?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a pretty specific question if anyone could help that would be awesome.

[image: Screenshot of billboard100 webpage]

I am trying to scrape the songs from https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/
and I am stuck on this code.

What should I put for `tag = soup.find_all('???')` to get the title 'About Damn Time.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/'

song_title = []


res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
tag = soup.find_all('???')
print(tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select the row containers, iterate the `ResultSet` get your expected text from the `<h3>`:

```
for e in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'o-chart-results-list-row-container'}):
    print(e.h3.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Example

If you try to store different information, avoid a bunch of differnet lists. Instead use one list with dict of each item and its information.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

data = []

for e in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'o-chart-results-list-row-container'}):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h3.get_text(strip=True),
        'author':e.h3.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
    })

data
```

Comment: Hedgehog, can i bother you again.

I want to get the song author this time, but changing list.append(e.span.get_text(strip=True)) does not work, why is this so?

Comment: Selection is not that specific, cause it try to select the first `span` in container, may change to `e.h3.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)` or `e.h3.find_next_sibling('span').get_text(strip=True)` -> Check also my edits to te example.

Comment: Hi hedgehog. Sorry to bother you again. Assuming I want to get the 6th `span` under the h3 element.

`'movie_genre': e.p.find_next(r'span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)`

the above works, however, is there another way to do this?

Comment: It's no problem to ask, that's what the platform is for. However, this would be predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exactly this focus and above all a little more context, as I can't find any movie under the [link](https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422489/web-scrape-with-bs-alternative-method-to-find-next

here!