# Web Scrape with BS alternative method to .find_next()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the movies from https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055592025/ and this is my code. It works, but is there a way to write it without the multiple .find_next() function?

````
import bs4

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055592025/'

data = []

res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for e in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':"lister-item mode-detail"}):
    data.append({
    'movie_title': e.h3.a.get_text(strip=True),
    'release_date': e.h3.find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True).strip('(').strip(')'),
    'movie_duration': e.p.find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True),
    'movie_genre': e.p.find_next(r'span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)

})

for d in data:
    print(d)```
````

Comment: Is this your code? This is code to scrape imdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements more specific by its class to avoid chaining `find_next()`, in this case they look static and not that dynamic:

```
'movie_genre': e.select_one('.genre').get_text(strip=True)
```

Alternative could be to use `pseudo classes` like `:nth-of-type()` or `:last-of-type` but be aware, that the structure has to be always the same:

```
'release_date': e.h3.select_one('span:last-of-type').get_text(strip=True).strip('(').strip(')'),
'movie_duration': e.select_one('p span:nth-of-type(3)').get_text(strip=True),
'movie_genre': e.select_one('p span:last-of-type').get_text(strip=True)
```

###### Example

```
import bs4
import requests
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055592025/'

data = []
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for e in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':"lister-item mode-detail"}):
    data.append({
    'movie_title': e.h3.a.get_text(strip=True),
    'release_date': e.select_one('.lister-item-year').get_text(strip=True).strip('(').strip(')'),
    'movie_duration': e.select_one('.runtime').get_text(strip=True),
    'movie_genre': e.select_one('.genre').get_text(strip=True)

})   
data
```